# Use compound indexes when using Acts as tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 3.2 web app and I am using [Acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/) gem as for multi tenancy. When using this gem I have to add a field called account_id to all my models. So when I do this Project.find(1) it uses a scope so that account_id is always in the query. My question is this:

Do I need to add a compound index to Project model? Since I am searching with both account_id (gem does that) and project_id show I have an index with those two together? Right now I have individual indexes on each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this to be a pretty good resource about indexing - but before reading it I was fairly clueless.  I think it depends on your current understanding.  It's a bit old, but the general idea hasn't change...check it out!

https://web.archive.org/web/20150923034803/https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations

and this one that specifically addresses compound indexing -

https://web.archive.org/web/20140426154227/https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-choosing-additional-indexes

Comment: The links are not working. It would be great if you could share some points from the article in the answer.

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan i updated the links via wayback machine

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much about Acts_as_tenant gem (never used) but theoretically speaking, if from whatever reason you are now on querying on the `id` and an `account_id` field, then **yes** you need to add a compound index to cover those queries.

Just make sure the gem is not adding an extra index by default.